# Как правльно выводить информацию в консоль при многопотоке?

Tags: python, python-3.x, многопоточность, threading

Я пишу многопоточное(`threading`) консольное приложение на Python, мне необходимо выводить информацию в консоль из всех потоков,но при использовании `print()` не понятно к какому потоку относиться информация и вообще информация трудно читаема.
Как правильнее и удобнее выводить информацию?

Comment: Ну обычно в начале каждой строки выводят какой-нибудь идентификатор потока. Какого-то универсального идеального решения нет.

Comment: @AlexeyTen ,так я тоже пробывал,но читаемость это не повешает

Comment: Ну если не нужно хранить предыдущее сообщение то все просто - выделить каждому потоку по строке и пусть туда пишет. Там многопоточные прогрессбары работают.

Comment: Зависит от задачи. Если это типа логирование, то вместо `print` используйте модуль `logging`. Во-первых, там легко добавить дополнительную информацию, типа времени и потока ко всем сообщениям глобально. Во-вторых, модуль позаботится о том чтоб вывод не перемешивался. Если же это сложный UI где разные потоки выводят свои данные, то возможно, вы ищете https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA ,попробую

Answer (score 3, accepted):

%(processName)s и %(threadName)s для logging format

```
import logging, multiprocessing

formatter = '%(asctime)s levelname[%(levelname)s] processName[%(processName)s] threadName[%(threadName)s] pathname[%(pathname)s] funcName[%(funcName)s] lineno[%(lineno)d]\n%(message)s'
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, datefmt='%H:%M:%S', format=formatter, handlers=[logging.StreamHandler(), ],)

def threads(n):
    logging.info(f'mp {n}')
    with multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool(processes=2) as p:
        p.map(lambda i: logging.info(f'th {i}'), range(3))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    multiprocessing.freeze_support()
    logging.info('Start')
    with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=2) as p:
        p.map(threads, range(2))
```

out:

```
13:08:05 levelname[INFO] processName[MainProcess] threadName[MainThread] pathname[C:\SCR\NEW_JIRA\sdas.py] funcName[<module>] lineno[13]
Start
13:08:06 levelname[INFO] processName[SpawnPoolWorker-2] threadName[MainThread] pathname[C:\SCR\NEW_JIRA\sdas.py] funcName[threads] lineno[7]
mp 0
13:08:06 levelname[INFO] processName[SpawnPoolWorker-2] threadName[Thread-1 (worker)] pathname[C:\SCR\NEW_JIRA\sdas.py] funcName[<lambda>] lineno[9]
th 0
13:08:06 levelname[INFO] processName[SpawnPoolWorker-2] threadName[Thread-1 (worker)] pathname[C:\SCR\NEW_JIRA\sdas.py] funcName[<lambda>] lineno[9]
th 1
13:08:06 levelname[INFO] processName[SpawnPoolWorker-2] threadName[Thread-1 (worker)] pathname[C:\SCR\NEW_JIRA\sdas.py] funcName[<lambda>] lineno[9]
th 2
13:08:06 levelname[INFO] processName[SpawnPoolWorker-2] threadName[MainThread] pathname[C:\SCR\NEW_JIRA\sdas.py] funcName[threads] lineno[7]
mp 1
13:08:06 levelname[INFO] processName[SpawnPoolWorker-2] threadName[Thread-6 (worker)] pathname[C:\SCR\NEW_JIRA\sdas.py] funcName[<lambda>] lineno[9]
th 0
13:08:06 levelname[INFO] processName[SpawnPoolWorker-2] threadName[Thread-6 (worker)] pathname[C:\SCR\NEW_JIRA\sdas.py] funcName[<lambda>] lineno[9]
th 1
13:08:06 levelname[INFO] processName[SpawnPoolWorker-2] threadName[Thread-6 (worker)] pathname[C:\SCR\NEW_JIRA\sdas.py] funcName[<lambda>] lineno[9]
th 2
```